# div's inside a div weird space behavior

Tags: html, css

[Website](http://www.rocketleague-base.com/) 
Problem is that the content_right div always appears on the bottom right of the last content_left div. Now, `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;` on #layout div does solve this problem but it completely disregards the height so that it has no `background-color`. As my height is dynamic i cant use `float:left;`, neither can i just `margin-top: -value;`. Couldn't find a solution here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ either. `position: absolute;` on `#layout_right` works similar to `float:left;`, `position: relative;` on `#layout` hasnt helped fix that.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F0641D;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
}
a {
  color: #F0641D;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #383838;
}
#header_content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_content div {
  float: left;
}
#header_logo {
  width: 114px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#header_navbar {
  width: 772px;
  text-align: center;
}
#header_navbar div {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #505050;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
}
#header_navbar div a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 15.5px 25px;
}
#header_navbar div:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F0641D;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#layout {
  width: 976px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #383838;
}
#layout div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#layout_left {
  width: 684px;
  margin: 0 16px -16px 0;
}
#content_left {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}
#content_right {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Center of Rocket League eSports!</title>
  <link href="style.php" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://quersteil.eu//data/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="RocketLeague-Base provides every aspect of Rocket League eSports: News, Matches, Results, Events, Statistics and many more" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_content">
      <div id="header_logo">
        <a href="http://quersteil.eu/"></a>
      </div>

      <div id="header_navbar">
        <div id="news"><a href="index.php?page=news">News</a>
        </div>
        <div id="matches"><a href="index.php?page=matches">Matches</a>
        </div>
        <div id="results"><a href="index.php?page=results">Results</a>
        </div>
        <div id="events"><a href="index.php?page=events">Events</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats"><a href="index.php?page=stats">Stats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="layout">
    <div id="layout_left">
      <div id="content_left">
        <div id="heading">Welcome to RocketLeague-Base.com!</div>
        <br>This site is currently under construction and is getting developed further and further everyday, be sure to check every now and then. When the site has finished it will be a data and information driven website all around Rocket League, comparable
        towards <a href="http://www.hltv.org/" target="_blank">HLTV.org</a>. Rocket League eSports is on the rise and as are the expectations of everyone watching, to have an easy way looking for all the eSports action surrounding Rocket League. We are
        in the makings of finishing the website as soon as possible, so that every Rocket League fan has a comfortable way to look at all News, Matches, Results, Events and Stats all around the great RL-eSports Scene. No need to go to 5 different webpages
        anymore to look at upcoming matches or past Results, RocketLeague-Base.com is the solution!
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
 
 -->
    <div id="layout_right">
      <div id="content_right">
        <img src="data/facebook.png">
        <img src="data/twitter.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you are missing the background colour you need to use a clear on your div: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: If you float `layout_right` and you lose the height, you can add `overflow` to recalculate: `#layout {overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: @blonfu yep, thanks. i solved it already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the #layout_right div to be on right side of the content, just add the below to ur css...

```
#layout_right {
    float:right;
}
```

This will solve!

Comment: adding `float: left;` to layout_left and `float: right;` to #layout_right did the trick, plus adding `overflow: hidden;` to my parent div: #layout added the background-color again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have this "space symbol messes my width calculation" problem. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq9zc96L/) a simpler illustration of that issue:

with this HTML you actually have space symbols between the divs in the markup and those are converted into 1 space symbol in DOM:

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="center">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

but if you put them this way, there will be no extra space and hence they will fit the container:

```
<div class="left">
</div><div class="center">
</div><div class="right">
</div>
```

One have to take care of this once (s)he uses `inline-block` elements since they are "inline" and in that line other symbols (including spaces) are placed.

PS yeap, here's your snippet modified in the corresponding manner, content_right is now on the right (see the snippet below). But you also have another issue: by default, `inline-block` elements are positioned by baseline and hence the right colomn is on the bottom, so I also added:

```
#layout_right {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**And now here's what you need:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F0641D;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
}
a {
  color: #F0641D;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #383838;
}
#header_content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_content div {
  float: left;
}
#header_logo {
  width: 114px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#header_navbar {
  width: 772px;
  text-align: center;
}
#header_navbar div {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #505050;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
}
#header_navbar div a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 15.5px 25px;
}
#header_navbar div:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F0641D;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#layout {
  width: 976px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #383838;
}
#layout div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#layout_left {
  width: 684px;
  margin: 0 16px -16px 0;
}
#content_left {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}
#layout_right {
    vertical-align:top;
}
#content_right {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Center of Rocket League eSports!</title>
  <link href="style.php" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://quersteil.eu//data/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="RocketLeague-Base provides every aspect of Rocket League eSports: News, Matches, Results, Events, Statistics and many more" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_content">
      <div id="header_logo">
        <a href="http://quersteil.eu/"></a>
      </div>

      <div id="header_navbar">
        <div id="news"><a href="index.php?page=news">News</a>
        </div>
        <div id="matches"><a href="index.php?page=matches">Matches</a>
        </div>
        <div id="results"><a href="index.php?page=results">Results</a>
        </div>
        <div id="events"><a href="index.php?page=events">Events</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats"><a href="index.php?page=stats">Stats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="layout">
    <div id="layout_left">
      <div id="content_left">
        <div id="heading">Welcome to RocketLeague-Base.com!</div>
        <br>This site is currently under construction and is getting developed further and further everyday, be sure to check every now and then. When the site has finished it will be a data and information driven website all around Rocket League, comparable
        towards <a href="http://www.hltv.org/" target="_blank">HLTV.org</a>. Rocket League eSports is on the rise and as are the expectations of everyone watching, to have an easy way looking for all the eSports action surrounding Rocket League. We are
        in the makings of finishing the website as soon as possible, so that every Rocket League fan has a comfortable way to look at all News, Matches, Results, Events and Stats all around the great RL-eSports Scene. No need to go to 5 different webpages
        anymore to look at upcoming matches or past Results, RocketLeague-Base.com is the solution!
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div><!-- removed white-space here! --><div id="layout_right">
      <div id="content_right">
        <img src="data/facebook.png">
        <img src="data/twitter.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F0641D;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
}
a {
  color: #F0641D;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #383838;
}
#header_content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_content div {
  float: left;
}
#header_logo {
  width: 114px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#header_navbar {
  width: 772px;
  text-align: center;
}
#header_navbar div {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #505050;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
}
#header_navbar div a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 15.5px 25px;
}
#header_navbar div:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F0641D;
  background-color: #505050;
}
#layout {
  width: 976px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #383838;
  display: flex;
}

#layout_left {
  width: 684px;
  margin: 0 16px -16px 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}

#layout_right {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #F0641D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Center of Rocket League eSports!</title>
  <link href="style.php" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://quersteil.eu//data/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="RocketLeague-Base provides every aspect of Rocket League eSports: News, Matches, Results, Events, Statistics and many more" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_content">
      <div id="header_logo">
        <a href="http://quersteil.eu/"></a>
      </div>

      <div id="header_navbar">
        <div id="news"><a href="index.php?page=news">News</a>
        </div>
        <div id="matches"><a href="index.php?page=matches">Matches</a>
        </div>
        <div id="results"><a href="index.php?page=results">Results</a>
        </div>
        <div id="events"><a href="index.php?page=events">Events</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats"><a href="index.php?page=stats">Stats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="layout">
    <div id="layout_left">
      <div id="content_left">
        <div id="heading">Welcome to RocketLeague-Base.com!</div>
        <br>This site is currently under construction and is getting developed further and further everyday, be sure to check every now and then. When the site has finished it will be a data and information driven website all around Rocket League, comparable
        towards <a href="http://www.hltv.org/" target="_blank">HLTV.org</a>. Rocket League eSports is on the rise and as are the expectations of everyone watching, to have an easy way looking for all the eSports action surrounding Rocket League. We are
        in the makings of finishing the website as soon as possible, so that every Rocket League fan has a comfortable way to look at all News, Matches, Results, Events and Stats all around the great RL-eSports Scene. No need to go to 5 different webpages
        anymore to look at upcoming matches or past Results, RocketLeague-Base.com is the solution!
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div id="content_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
 
 -->
    <div id="layout_right">
      <div id="content_right">
        <img src="data/facebook.png">
        <img src="data/twitter.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```